# Usage of Repetitive words

Tags: expression-choice

we often repeat few words in like little little , different different etc . Are these valid english usage?

Comment: "we often" is not sufficient context, sorry. Who are "we"? Nobody can answer your question without knowing what the repetition is sposta mean, and who does it when.

Comment: I'd like to add that I've never heard the word *different* used multiple times consecutively.

Comment: is this really a dupe? i took this question to mean "can you repeat a word to make it stronger?"

Answer (score 0):

Word repetition is not valid usage in English.  It is considered an error.  I am aware that some other languages replicate words to provide emphasis.  In English, the use of a modifier is required.

Something is small.

Somethings is **very** small indeed.